# How to calculate Hamming distance in Matlab for two 3*3 Matrixes

Tags: matlab

Hi I have a pair of 3*3 matrix and I want to calculate the Hamming distance of these;
I found [that](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/pdist.html) and [that](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/48131) , but i can not applied it I m using 2011 version of Matlab.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function in your second link, slightly modified:

```
hamming_dist = @(a,b)sum(a(:)~=b(:))
```

As a simple example enter the following:

```
>> hamming_dist = @(a,b)sum(a(:)~=b(:));
>> hamming_dist(eye(3), zeros(3))
ans =

 3
```